# Python igraph adds edge in the wrong direction

Tags: python, igraph

Why is Python-igraph adding the last edge in the wrong direction in the following example? how can I prevent that?

```
from igraph import *

graph = Graph()
graph.add_vertices(10)
graph.add_edge(0,1)
graph.add_edge(1,4)
graph.add_edge(1,5)
graph.add_edge(1,3)
graph.add_edge(2,3)
graph.add_edge(4,6)
graph.add_edge(6,7)
graph.add_edge(6,8)
graph.add_edge(9,8)

graph.as_directed() # Same result with or without this line

print graph.es[8].tuple # (8, 9)
```

Comment: It's not a directed graph by default. Try `Graph(directed=True)`.

Comment: Oops, I missed that option. Makes sense. Thanks a lot!